# What's better to remove all options from a dropdown? dropdown.find('option').remove() vs. dropdown.empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume that `dropdown` is a `<select>` element.

**Both ways do the job.**

I think that `empty()` will be faster since I don't call `find()` but I would like to ask the community, what are your thoughts?

Any figures? Comparison?

Comment: May be `dropdown.html('')` as `.empty` is implemented like this: `while (elem.firstChild)` and with `.find`, there will be a `loop`

Comment: make select innerhtml empty..

Comment: First you need to define "*better*."

Comment: @DavidThomas, faster, more efficient, more optimal, consuming less memory etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dropdown.empty()` will also remove if there are any [optgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) inside it, while `dropdown.find('option').remove()` will only specically remove `options` from it.

`empty` is [faster by 400%](https://coderwall.com/p/nygghw/don-t-use-innerhtml-to-empty-dom-elements) then you can take a call based on whether you want to remove any other child element inside `select` (other than `option`) or not.

If you want to remove all, then use `dropdown.empty()`, if you want to remove only options then use `dropdown.find('option').remove()`.

Comment: I don't know which one is faster and that's the reason why I created this topic. PS. I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: @RayonDabre Empty is much faster. As per link I have attached, it is about 400 times faster than `innerHTML`.

Comment: @gurvinder372, That is fine.. But this what you need to put in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1) dropdown.empty()  its  means all the options in the dropdown has removed totally.
2) dropdown.find('option').empty()  its  means all the options are there and only removed options text only.

3) $('.dropdown').remove(); its means dropdown also removed .
4)  $('.dropdown').find('option').remove(); its means  remove the  all the options

Comment: And first you should know the difference between empty and remove.  empty means only inner value is removed. where as remove means the total element is removed

Answer (score 0):

- `empty()` will remove all the contents of the selection. `remove()` will
  remove the selection and its contents.

### Consider:

**foo**

```
$('p').empty();  // --> "<div><p></p></div>"

// whereas,
$('p').remove(); // --> "<div></div>"
```

Both of them remove the DOM objects and should release the memory they take up,